# Need more metadata while querying https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search

Tags: rest, restful-url, ebay-api

I am querying `https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?q=t-shirts` to find available products. However, I am facing a challenge in obtaining crucial information from the API response, specifically, the 'size' and 'brand' details of the shirts.

I have extensively reviewed the API documentation at https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item_summary/methods/search, but unfortunately, I couldn't locate any information that would provide me with the required details.

If anyone has experience or insights on how to retrieve 'size' and 'brand' information from this API, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try here and join their community.. https://community.ebay.com/t5/Developer-Forums/ct-p/developergroup